# How can manipulate different variables with similar names in a for loop in r?

Tags: r, for-loop, variable-names

I have 9 data frames here, data01 to data09. My question is, how to get the column names of each data frame using for loop in r? The paste syntax didn't work.

```
for (i in 1: 9) {
  print(colnames(paste("data0", i, sep = "")))
}
```

Comment: How did you create these 9 data frames in the first place? If you have related data it's easier to work with them in R if you store them in a named list. Then you can easily apply functions over that list. `paste()` will just return a string. Strings are different than actual variable names.

Comment: thank you very much! I have solved it. just use get() .